# Splitting a directory with images into sub folders using Pytorch or Python

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a directory with two sub directories in it. Each sub-dir has bunch of images. These sub-dir also specify the two classes of images.

I want to have 3 directories (train, validation, test) and within each of these 3 sub dir, I want to 2 sub directory of each class respectively with images.

I want to split the no.of images into train, val, test directories by random sampling. SO some 60% images go to train, 20, val and 20 in test.

Initial Structure:

```
Main_folder
 - Good
 - Bad
```

What I want:

```
Main_folder: 
 - Train 
  - Good
  - Bad
 - Val
  - Good 
  - Bad
 - Test 
  - Good 
  - Bad
```

I want to split each sub directories into two directories within it with random assignment of images (

Answer (score 7):

There is a `pytorch` way to do that (and I would advise using single library for such easy task).

### Creating dataset

There is a pre-made one inside `torchvision`, namely [`ImageFolder`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/datasets.html#imagefolder).

Simply use it like this:

```
import torchvision

dataset = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder("./my_data")
```

This will create a dataset, where `Good` folder has `0` label and `Bad` has label of `1` for each image in those folder respectively.

### Dividing into train, validation, test

No need for `sklearn` for such an easy job + `torch` has most of the `numpy` functionality as well and I would rather stick with one library instead of 3 (though `train_test_split` could be used twice consecutively, similar to what [@ESZ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58105073/splitting-a-directory-with-images-into-sub-folders-using-pytorch-or-python/58105788#58105788) proposed).

IMO simpler would be:

```
def get_subset(indices, start, end):
    return indices[start : start + end]


TRAIN_PCT, VALIDATION_PCT = 0.6, 0.2  # rest will go for test
train_count = int(len(dataset) * TRAIN_PCT)
validation_count = int(len(dataset) * VALIDATION_PCT)

indices = torch.randperm(len(dataset))

train_indices = get_subset(indices, 0, train_count)
validation_indices = get_subset(indices, train_count, validation_count)
test_indices = get_subset(indices, train_count + validation_count, len(dataset))
```

This will create indices for `SubsetRandomSampler` and `torch.utils.data.DataLoader`.
So, similarly to [@ESZ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58105073/splitting-a-directory-with-images-into-sub-folders-using-pytorch-or-python/58105788#58105788) once again:

```
dataloaders = {
    "train": torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        dataset, sampler=SubsetRandomSampler(train_indices)
    ),
    "validation": torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        dataset, sampler=SubsetRandomSampler(validation_indices)
    ),
    "test": torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        dataset, sampler=SubsetRandomSampler(test_indices)
    ),
}
```

You can specify `batch_size` and other argument to `DataLoader`, see [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader) if you need more info.

Comment: This does not save the split into folders however, right?

Comment: No, why would it?

Comment: Ah ok. Just thought from the wording of the question, that that is what the OP wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not sure about the Good-Bad stuff but I'm pretty sure that you can use scipy train-test split function.

You can find detailed information in [sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)
I guess it only creates two samples of image sets like train-test. However, you can divide the test part again to achieve your goal. Also, as I remember you can set the train-test percentage in the function as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts of this problem:

1. Given a list of files, find an algorithm that randomly generates subsets of given proportion.
2. Shuffle the actual files around based on the subsets generated.

Two is a trivial use case of `os` package and answered elsewhere. For 1, the algorithm is (pseudocode):

```
for d in [Good, Bad]:
    n['all'] = total images in d
    for c in [Train, Val, Test]:
        if not last_item:
            n[c] = round(n['all'] * proportion[c])
        else:
            n[c] = n['all'] - all other n's

    shuffle list of all images in d
    for c in [Train, Val, Test]:
        take first n[c] images and put them in c
        remove them from d
```

In this case, the Good/Bad ratio will be the same in every subset as in the original input, which is not a bad idea. The split can be done in other ways, but that is a broad discussion I won't get into here. However, you might need at least 100 images or more for this to work - splitting just 40 images into 6 subsets doesn't really make much sense, they'd be too small.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SKLearn's train_test_split + SubSetRandomSampler from torch as follow :

```
from torch.utils.data.sampler import SubsetRandomSampler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from torch.utils.data.sampler import SubsetRandomSampler
valid_size_and_test = 0.4 # then I will keep 0.1 for testing 

## split the dataset into train and rest data
targets = dataset.targets

train_idx, rest_idx = train_test_split(np.arange(len(targets)), test_size= 
                    valid_size_and_test, random_state=42, shuffle=True, stratify=targets)
test_size = int(len(rest_idx) * valid_size_and_test)
valid_idx, test_idx = rest_idx[:test_size], rest_idx[test_size:]

dataloaders = {'trainLoader' : torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset,batch_size=32,sampler=SubsetRandomSampler(train_idx)),
               'validLoader' : torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset,batch_size=32,sampler=SubsetRandomSampler(valid_idx)),
               'testLoader' :  torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset,batch_size=32,sampler=SubsetRandomSampler(test_idx)),
              }
```

Comment: how is dataset.targets?

Comment: It's a torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder loader : `dataset  = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(train_dir,transform=My_transforms)`  by calling datasettargets you will get the target of a given image that is the folder name on which this image is